# convert image array to string

Tags: python, image

Below code can convert actual image to string, but I want to convert image array (32, 32, 3) to string, how to do that without constructing array to actual image?

```
import base64

with open('Icon_yes.JPG', "rb") as image_file:
    encoded_string = base64.b64encode(image_file.read())
```

Thank you

Comment: do you mean convert array without saving in file ? You can use `io.BytesIO` to create file in memory, save in this file and later convert it to base64 - it is popular method to generate `png` in web framework and send it to browser. Eventually you can use `data = cv2.imencode('.jpg', np.array)` to convert it to jpg (or png) before converting to base64

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want a simple(without constructing array to actual image) and use base64

maybe you shoule use ply or cv2

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import base64
# this this the arr
img_arr = plt.imread(r"1.jpg")

plt.imsave('Icon_yes.jpg', img_arr)
with open('Icon_yes.JPG', "rb") as image_file:
    encoded_string = base64.b64encode(image_file.read())
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your image array is a numpy array you can simply use the `.tostring()` method.

```
import numpy as np

img_arr = np.random.rand(32, 32, 3)
img_arr.tostring()
```

Comment: I tried this way, but the string is something like ```\x80\x0e\xe6B\xce\\\xa6B\xd2```, I would prefer base64 encoded string ```DAQkJCQwLDBgNDRgyIRwhMj``` but do not want to construct and save image first. Thank you.